# Python MySQL Unpack Results from cur.fetchall()

Tags: python, mysql

I have a query in Python and when I use `row = cur.fetchone()` or `rows = cur.fetchall()`, I am unable to properly unpack the values.

```
import pymysql.cursors
cur.execute(QUERY)
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    col1_data, col2_data, col3_data = row
```

I would expect `col#_data` to contain the corresponding value but it just has the label. If I do `print(row)` I get:

> {'post_author': 'USERNAME', 'newposts': Decimal('52'), 'reposts': Decimal('50')}

How can I unpack the mysql values?

Comment: Can you dereference objects like that?

Comment: @Anthony, it is not dereferencing, it is just assigning/unpacking the values to their own variable name. See my solution for what I ended up doing.

Comment: wouldn't `col1_data, col2_data, col3_data = row.values()` worked just as well, then?

Comment: `list(row.values())` but yes that is what I ended up doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution. The problem is that I am treating row like a list but pymysql returns a dictionary. When I do `a,b,c=row`, the values of a,b,c are set to the keys (column headers) of `row`.

The trick is to access the values of the dictionary and convert them to a list.

```
a, b, c = list(row.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Access `row` just like a dictionary:

```
for row in rows:
    post_author = row['post_author']
    newposts = row['newposts']
    reposts = row['newposts']
```